# Air travel without known date

Tags: air-travel, usa, tickets, insurance, israel

I am planning a year long trip from the USA to Israel in the near future, however due to personal reasons I may have to delay the trip from anywhere from a few weeks to a few months.

That being the case, I am wondering if there is some ticket purchasing scheme where I would be better off than simply waiting  until I know when I am traveling to purchase a ticket (which may be within a week or so of when I would actually leave).

For example, is there a type of ticket with low/no rescheduling fees that would generally end up cheaper than booking a somewhat last minute ticket? Or some sort of insurance?

Comment: The greater risk *not* being able to book at the last minute. Airlines tend to operate at capacity and even frequently overbook nowadays.

Comment: @Itai so I guess part of the question is really, is there anything to do to mitigate that besides randomly guessing on a date to buy a ticket for.

Comment: Not randomly, choose it in low season, so that the price is lowest.

Answer (score 8):

A flexible ticket will cost you roughly the most the airline ever might charge for a given route. This is a corollary of yield management: if a flexible ticket would ever be significantly cheaper than the price at any time then it would make good sense for a business traveler to buy up flexible tickets and mess with the airline's carefully crafted numbers.

So no, you can't and there's no way around this. Airlines are notoriously protective of the yield management model, this is why you can't change names at most airlines for example.